# How to invoke ValueEventListener of firebase programatically in android

Tags: android, firebase

```
student_edit.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) 
    {
        noof_placed=0;
        placpercent=0.0;
        enrolled=0;

        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) 
        {

            StudentDetail std = 
            postSnapshot.getValue(StudentDetail.class);
            std.setRollno(postSnapshot.getKey());
            studentlist.add(std);
            enrolled++;


            if (!std.getPlacementcompany().toString().trim().equals("0")) 
            {

                noof_placed++;

            }
        }
        placpercent=(noof_placed / total_students) * 100;
        start_progressbar(noof_placed,placpercent);
   }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) 
    {
    }
});
```

This is my listener for retrieving data from firebase it will be triggered when data changes in firebase. how can I invoke this listener programmatically

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. please elaborate it with more detail

Answer (score 0):

```
student_edit.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

       // do your task
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

   }
});
```

Call this method whenever you requires. It will not run everytime when data is inserted in firebase.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger your listener, you can either write to the database `student_edit` location, or isolate the listener and then call that. I assume that writing to the database is self-explanatory. To isolate the listener, you could add a member field to your class:

```
ValueEventListener studentListener;
```

Then initialize that field and set the listener based on it:

```
studentListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) 
    {
        noof_placed=0;
        placpercent=0.0;
        enrolled=0;

        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) 
        {

            StudentDetail std = 
            postSnapshot.getValue(StudentDetail.class);
            std.setRollno(postSnapshot.getKey());
            studentlist.add(std);
            enrolled++;


            if (!std.getPlacementcompany().toString().trim().equals("0")) 
            {

                noof_placed++;

            }
        }
        placpercent=(noof_placed / total_students) * 100;
        start_progressbar(noof_placed,placpercent);
   }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) 
    {
    }
});
student_edit.addValueEventListener(studentListener);
```

And then you can call it anywhere with:

```
studentListener.onDataChange(YOUR_SNAPSHOT);
```

Of course the problem becomes that you then need to keep the snapshot around.

Comment: I have to change database reference of  "student_edit"  dynamically. Once the reference has changed it has to trigger the ValueEventListener of "student_edit" object with a new set of data. I would be grateful for your solution.

Comment: That means that you'll need to attach the listener to the new value of `student_edit`, and probably [remove the listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#detach_listeners) from the old value of `student_edit`