# Detect value change with firebase ValueEventListener

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, event-listener

I am trying to detect value change from my Firebase Database. Here is my code for initializing the ValueEventListener:

```
valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            try {
                String customerLocation = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
                Point customerPoint = locationFounder.getPoint(customerLocation);

                if (customerPoint != null) {
                    databaseReference.child("isActive").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            boolean isActive = Boolean.valueOf(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue()));

                            displayPopUp(isActive, customerPoint, customerLocation);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Listener",e.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    destinationReference.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

Problem occurs when I want to call this listener in my activity. I've been trying with this:

```
destinationListener.getValueEventListener().onDataChange(REQUIRED_SNAPSHOT);
```

I do not know how can I get datasnapshot which is required for onDataChange. I would like to get this work with ValueEventListener, not ChildEventListener, if possible. However, I am not pretty sure that this is the right way of trying to detect value change. If there is any other way that will work properly, I'd like to know about it.

Comment: You can't create your own `DataSnapshot`. Why do you need to do that?

Comment: Because I need the snapshot as a parameter to call the function destinationListener.getValueEventListener().onDataChange(REQUIRED_SNAPSHOT);
 (I named it REQUIRED_SNAPSHOT because I do not know what should be there). However, if you know any other way to do this, it would be nice if you can help :)

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to make that call in your code? I've never had the need to call listeners myself, and only rely on Firebase to call them.

Comment: Referring to your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51367944/how-to-invoke-valueeventlistener-of-firebase-programatically-in-android/51368154#51368154 I tried to implement it in my app. However, I am again saying that I am not sure this is the right approach, but I am open to learn how to detect when specific value in firebase database is changed. Thanks!

Comment: That assume you have a snapshot of the previous data. As said in my first comment, you can't create a snapshot yourself.

Comment: Okay, I understand. So, can you please tell me how can I listen for the change of specific value in the firebase database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built to the Firebase Realtime Database to tell you what specific data under the snapshot has changed in the `onDataChange` method.

If you want to know what specific property has change, you'll need to:

1. Keep the snapshot that you get in `onDataChange` in a field.
2. When `onDataChange` gets called, compare the data in the new snapshot with the data in the field.

Say that you have a reference on a node in your JSON, and under that node is a `status` property, and you want to both listen to the entire node, and detect if the `status` has changed.

You'd do that with something like:

```
// Add a field to your class to keep the latest snapshot
DataSnapshot previousSnapshot;

// Then add your listener
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        bool wasActive = false;
        if (previousSnapshot != null && previousSnapshot.child("status").exists()) {
            wasActive = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue(Boolean.class);
        }
        boolean isActive = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue(Boolean.class);

        if (isActive <> wasActive) {
            ... the user's status changed
        }

        previousSnapshot = dataSnapshot;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I can detect value change now!

Comment: Remember to remove the ValueEventListener from the DatabaseReference when it's no longer valid (like onDestroy() of you activity or fragment)